# styles in header, each for a different fieldset

Tags: html, css, colors, styles, border

I have 2 fieldsets and I need to use different border colors for both, and the style needs to be in the header
How do I differentiate from both fieldsets?

I only know about this:

```
<style type="text/css">
            fieldset {border-color:red;}
        </style>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add classes to distinguish them.

**html tag**

```
<fieldset class="set-1">
    <!-- your code here -->
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="set-2">
    <!-- your code here -->
</fieldset>
```

**CSS code**

```
fieldset.set-1 {border-color:red;}
fieldset.set-2 {border-color:green;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `fieldset:first-child` look this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9myb01ma/), just clear your question so we can help you, if i am right just check the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first-child` and `last-child` pseudo-selectors to do that

Simple example:

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Fieldset 1</legend>
    Content goes here 1
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Fieldset 2</legend>
    Content goes here 2
</fieldset>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Select first fieldset */
fieldset:first-child {
  background: #999;
  color: purple;
  border-color: purple;
}
/* Select last fieldset */
fieldset:last-child {
  border-color: green;
  color: green;
  background: white;
}
/* set some properties to all legends */
fieldset legend {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #111;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/an17t3d0/)</kbd>